# Excel linking both ways between two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

There are similar questions answered but mine is a simpler case, so I hope a "keystroke solution" exists.

I've done some calculations with formulas, using several intermediate cells. Now I want to give the result to somebody else who does not care about these intermediate computations, and I do not want them to be distracted by some hidden columns, so I prefer to keep all these intermediate cells on another sheet.

I can paste links there, but this won't help - what I need is that the cells in the new sheet refer to the cells in the old one, while the final results in the old sheet use values from the new sheet.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Does your colleague need the formulas in the final sheet, or just the end results? If the latter, use 'paste values' from your final sheet to the copied sheet you're going to share.

Comment: @AlexM No this won't do - they must be entering some values in some cells and see the final results in some other cells

Comment: Well, cell references can refer to other workbooks, so you could theoretically maintain a workbook with the intermediate calculations, and give your colleague access to a workbook that has formulas that reference those calculated fields; as long as the filepath of the calculating workbook stays constant, everything will work for your colleague. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AlexM Yes, and I obviously can just type in the paths in necessary places, I just want to know whether there is an easier way. For example, pasting links produces them automatically, but I want that also links would appear to the cells that I moved to another place.

Comment: in one workbook, type `=` then navigate to another workbook and select a cell. The result will come out like `=[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1` for example. If that data is moved in the source sheet, the formula will automatically update. Is that what you mean?